# project ID printed for every task on the API problem

Tags: python, excel, list, api, request

I have this code below, requesting an api. Every ID in listID loops 4 times in the url. So if the listID = [1,2,3,4,5], the url will be :
url = "https://xxxxapi/v1/implantacao/projeto/1/tarefa?start=0&limit=50" then
url = "https://xxxxapi/v1/implantacao/projeto/1/tarefa?start=1&limit=50" and etc, start goes 0 to 3 for every id in the list

Then, im saving every data request i get into and xls file and that's working fine. For example, every 4 loops at the id, normally returns 120 tasks. I want to print the ID for every task that the code returns, in the line :
#sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=1).value = listID

```
 def teste(id): 
      listID = (id)
      headers = {
            "xxxxxxxxx",
            "Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8"
        } 
      
      length = len(listID)
      nome = []
      codigoTarefa = []
      situacaoTarefa = []
      faseNome = []
      
      for li in range(length):
        for count in range(4):
          url = "https://xxxxapi/v1/implantacao/projeto/{}/tarefa?start={}&limit=50".format(listID[li], count)
          response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
          data = response.json()
    
          
          unidades2(data, nome, codigoTarefa, situacaoTarefa, faseNome)
      
      
      wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
      sheet = wb.active
    
      for i in range(len(nome)):
        #sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=1).value = listID
        sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=2).value = nome[i]
        sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=3).value = codigoTarefa[i]
        sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=4).value = situacaoTarefa[i]
        
      wb.save("dados11.xlsx")
      
          
    
    def unidades2(data, nome, codigoTarefa, situacaoTarefa, faseNome):
      workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
      sheet = workbook.add_sheet("BACKOFFICE")
      coluna = 1
      for i in data['data']:
        nome.append(i['nome'])
        codigoTarefa.append(i['codigo'])
        situacaoTarefa.append(i['situacao'])
        coluna +=1
        
       
      
      
     
      
    if __name__ == '__main__':
      Sults()
```

To be more clear : One output example from one task at project ID 1 :

INAUGURAÇÃO
T98
4

I want this output (1 is the first item in listID for example) :
1
INAUGURAÇÃO
T98
4

How can i get it ? Thanks for the help btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def teste(id): 
  listID = (id)# this is list of ids. Yes, that list you want this id go to the file xml. Yes, but the file today is a big one
  #print (listID)
  headers = {
        "Authorization":"xxxxxxxxxx",
        "Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    } 
  
  
  #A contagem do counter começa negativa pois eu quero que a primeira busca de página seja no valor 0 > que busca as primeiras 50 tarefas
  
  length = len(listID)
  nome = []
  codigoTarefa = []
  situacaoTarefa = []
  faseNome = []
  global ID_List
  ID_List = [] #but how did u get this list became an [254,254,254,254,255,255,255 etc]

  for li in range(length):
    for count in range(4):
      #o start dentro de url é o counter. Ou seja, ele vai até 4, a partir do 0
      url = "https://xxxxxxxxx.com/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/{}/tarefa?start={}&limit=50".format(listID[li], count) #here i got the id from the code above, and count is the pagination about api
      #print(url)
      response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
      data = response.json()

      
      unidades2(data, nome, codigoTarefa, situacaoTarefa, faseNome, listID[li])#li is legnth of  id list ok? Ok, i get it now. So )
  #print(nome)
  
  wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
  sheet = wb.active

  for i in range(len(nome)):
    sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=1).value = ID_List[i]
    sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=2).value = nome[i]
    sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=3).value = codigoTarefa[i]
    sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=4).value = situacaoTarefa[i]
    
  wb.save("dados12.xlsx")
  #print(codigoTarefa)
  #print(situacaoTarefa)
  #print(faseNome)
      

def unidades2(data, nome, codigoTarefa, situacaoTarefa, faseNome, ID):   # ok just wait secounds this ID here is the parameter to the above listID[li]
  workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
  sheet = workbook.add_sheet("BACKOFFICE")
  coluna = 1
  for i in data['data']:
    nome.append(i['nome'])
    codigoTarefa.append(i['codigo'])
    situacaoTarefa.append(i['situacao'])
    
    ID_List.append(ID)# append here
    coluna +=1
   
  
  
 
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
  Sults()
```

Comment: Gives an error because printed all the id List. I will try to explain more clearly : 

I have an id list in other function, and im calling as listID at this function 

listID = [236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269] 

Every id has a pagination, so im running a loop 4 times to get every page and every task from the projects. 

From every project (every id), i get 120 tasks (nome, codigo, situacao), that i get an list for each

Comment: But now, im only exporting every task (nome, codigo, situacao), and not every id too, because im only have the id in the url. 

I want my output : id, nome, codigo, situacao 

But now im struggling to get the id from the url or the correct id from the list

Comment: TRY NOW AFTER EDIT

Comment: the last ID_List(ID) >> name 'ID_List' is not defined 
Where do i use the loop counter, too ?

Comment: can i enter with remotly you use "anydisk"

Comment: for sure, send me an email please : henriquemazettiferraz@outlook.com 
I will answer there my contacts and my anydisk infos 

Thanks for the help btw, im struggling hard and you're taking your time to help my problem

Comment: i send msg to you on email

Comment: its worked, I very appreciate your help, like, give your time to help me with this question is so valuable to me. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably work because every four name elements you have, you have one listID.

```
sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=1).value = listID[i/4]
```

Edit:

I realize now that your listID is actually a tuple. I changed the code above to this. This should resolve the float error.

```
sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=1).value = listID[i//4]
```

Comment: list indices must be integers or slices, not float error 
I will try to explain more, for example listID = [236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269] 

url = "https://xxxxapi/v1/implantacao/projeto/256/tarefa?start=0&limit=50" 
url = "https://xxxxapi/v1/implantacao/projeto/256/tarefa?start=1&limit=50"
url = "https://xxxxapi/v1/implantacao/projeto/256/tarefa?start=2&limit=50"
url = "https://xxxxapi/v1/implantacao/projeto/256/tarefa?start=3&limit=50"

Comment: For every url loop, returns me tasks with name, code and situation. I want that returns me the url id from the loop too 

For example in the 256 example above : 

256 > ID (not printing today, thats what i want)
INAUGURACAO > Nome
T98 > codigo 
4 > situacao